# React Child component wont update props

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I'm new to react and i'm trying to create a Teams custom app.
I created a child component that shows a list of resources on a Popup - PopupResources -
that list gets updated after an async call.

i started to set that list on the parent state as empty (`this.setState({resources: []});`) and after the async call i set up a dummy list.
The child component prop (roomResources) is setted from the parent state.

But it seems that the child component is not getting updated - It's not showing the new list. Can you please help?

this is my code:

Parent:

```
const dummyRoomResources = [{ id:1, description: "r1", checked: false}, {id:2, description:"r2", checked: false}, {id:3, description:"r3", checked: false}]

export class MyTab extends TeamsBaseComponent<IMyTabProps, IMyTabState> {
        
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setState({resources: []});
        
     }
     
    public async componentWillMount() {
                
        this.updateComponentTheme(this.getQueryVariable("theme"));
        this.setState(
                    Object.assign({}, 
                                this.state, 
                                {                                    
                                    resources: []
                                }
                                )
                            );
        this.updateTheme(this.getQueryVariable("theme"));
               
        if (await this.inTeams()) {
                    ...
        } else {
            this.setState({
                        entityId: "This is not hosted in Microsoft Teams", paxNr: 0,
                        resources: dummyRoomResources
                    });
                   
        
        }
    }
    
    ...
    
    public render() {
            return (
              <Provider theme={ this.state.teamsTheme }>
                ...
                    <div>
                    
            <PopupResources roomResources={(this.state.resources)}></PopupResources>
```

Child Component:

```
export interface IPopupResourcesProps {
   roomResources: any[]
}

class PopupResources extends React.Component<IPopupResourcesProps, IPopupResourcesState> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
  }
  
  popupContent = (
    <>
      {

        this.props.roomResources.map(item => (
                          <Checkbox label={item.description}></Checkbox>
                                )
                        ) 
      }
      <br />
      
    </>
  )


  render(){
     return (
       <Popup
          trigger={
            <Input icon={<SettingsIcon />} placeholder="Recursos" type="text"  />
      
      }
      content={{
        content: this.popupContent,
        'aria-label': 'Recursos',
       }}
       trapFocus
/>
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up `popupContent` outside the `render()` method in the `PopupResources` component.

Move it inside `render()`

```
render () {
  const popupContent = ...

  ...
}
```

When props update, render re-runs, and you want to render `popupContent` based on the new value of `props.roomResources`.

At the moment, because you set up `popupContent` once outside of the render method, it's just a constant rendered with the initial value of `props.roomResources` (`[]`).